# no effect of cache-control no-store seen in nginx in chrome dev tools, why?

Tags: nginx

I first downloaded two images.

Put them into `/usr/share/nginx/html/img` directory.

One was named pic-1.jpg, another was named pic-2.jpg.

Remember, I've not added any cache control headers till date.

Now, I went to `my-ip-address:80/img/pic-1.jpg`. Then I clicked reload a couple of times, so that I can check dev tools and find cache stored there.

But to my surprise, I didn't find anything stored there.

```
# curl -I 192.168.1.76:80/img/pic1.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.20.1
Date: Fri, 01 Sep 2023 09:32:26 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 164619
Last-Modified: Fri, 01 Sep 2023 09:30:40 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "64f1af40-2830b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

This was the output being returned via terminal `curl`.

I could not open `about:cache` in google chrome at all, so had to look into chrome dev tools.